# Error in property accessor

Tags: c#-4.0, model-view-controller

We recently placed an MVC application in production that sometimes gives us unhandled errors that we cannot reproduce in our development environment. The web app keeps crashing on the same line but the inner exception gives different error messages. The line where it crashes is when a particular property is accessed (property accessor). But the inner exception gives us the following different errors:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

We have a large number of users so I'm assuming that this has to do with concurrency or some type of thread problem? Can someone guide me in the right direction on how to find the problem?

By the way, it crashes always when accessing the same property. Sometimes it works other times it fails.

Here is the code for the accessor:

```
public string DepartementSelectionne
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_departementSelectionne) == true)
                if (ListeDepartements.FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    m_departementSelectionne = ListeDepartements.First().CodeDepartement;

            return m_departementSelectionne;
        }
        set
        {
            m_departementSelectionne = value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to even make educated guesses without some code.

Comment: Just added the accessor code. Sorry.

Comment: Are you by chance using Linq to SQL or Entities?

Comment: I'm using LINQ to SQL.